# Unable to read an log file(server running log) from windows using flume

Tags: apache, spark-streaming, flume, flume-ng, spark-structured-streaming

Hi am facing an issue while reading an application's running log file from windows via apache flume. Please find the below configuration details i hace used in "flume-conf.properties"

```
# The configuration file needs to define the sources, 
# the channels and the sinks.
# Sources, channels and sinks are defined per agent, 
# in this case called 'agent'

wh.sources = ws
wh.channels = mem
wh.sinks = k1

# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
wh.sources.ws.type = exec
wh.sources.ws.command = tail -F C:/Users/nirmal.b/Desktop/serverlogs/serverlog.txt


# The channel can be defined as follows.
wh.sources.ws.channels = mem

# Each sink's type must be defined
wh.sinks.k1.type = logger

#Specify the channel the sink should use
wh.sinks.k1.channel = mem

# Each channel's type is defined.
wh.channels.mem.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
wh.channels.mem.capacity = 1000
wh.channels.mem.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

when i start executing the flume agent with the below command

```
flume-ng agent -n wh --conf ./conf/ -f C:/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf/flume-conf-serverlogs.properties
```

I am facing the below exception from flume

```
Sourcing environment configuration script ./conf/\flume-env.ps1
WARN: Did not find ./conf/\flume-env.ps1
Including Hadoop libraries found in (C:\hadoop-2.7.6) for DFS access
Including HBase libraries found via (C:\hbase-2.1.0) for HBase access
WARN: HIVE_HOME not found

  Running FLUME agent :
    class: org.apache.flume.node.Application
    arguments: -n wh -f "C:\apache-flume-1.8.0-bin\conf\flume-conf-serverlogs.properties"

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop-2.7.6/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:C:\apache-flume-1.8.0-bin\conf\flume-conf-serverlogs.properties
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:k1
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: k1 Agent: wh
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [wh]
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel mem type memory
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel mem
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source ws, type exec
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: k1, type: logger
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel mem connected to [ws, k1]
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{ws=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource{name:ws,state:IDLE} }}
sinkRunners:{k1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@2ebdc61b counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{mem=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChan
nel{name: mem}} }
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel mem
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: mem: Successfully registered new MBean.
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: mem started
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink k1
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO node.Application: Starting Source ws
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO source.ExecSource: Exec source starting with command: tail -F C:/Users/nirmal.b/Desktop/serverlogs/serverlog.txt
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: ws: Successfully registered new MBean.
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SOURCE, name: ws started
18/10/16 14:23:20 ERROR source.ExecSource: Failed while running command: tail -F C:/Users/nirmal.b/Desktop/serverlogs/serverlog.txt
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tail": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource$ExecRunnable.run(ExecSource.java:302)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 6 more
18/10/16 14:23:20 INFO source.ExecSource: Command [tail -F C:/Users/nirmal.b/Desktop/serverlogs/serverlog.txt] exited with -1073741824
```

I have attached the console image also [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5jgZ.png)

My goal is to stream the data from server log file in to hdfs via flume. kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tail** is a native Unix tool and a native GNU tool for linux system.
You do not have the command tail available on your system (windows).

**Solution 1**
Install [UnxUtils for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) so that the tail command is available on your windows system.
(make sure the tail command is present in your PATH environment variable).

**Solution 2**
Use a flume [Spooling Directory Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source%20%22%22) instead the exec flume source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Erms Solution 2 is working fine with the below configuration
I have downloaded the unxutils for windows and got copied it to E: can you provide the configuration example for the same. so that i will do the same kind of configuration, coz my log's are appending in the same file so i need to use exec only.
# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
wh.sources.ws.type = spooldir
wh.sources.ws.spoolDir = C:/Users/nirmal.b/Desktop/serverlogs
wh.sources.ws.fileHeader = true

Comment: Solution-1 got worked after adding the Path to environment variables. Thanks for your suggestion.